# scheme - string-appends wrong type to apply error

Tags: string, list, scheme, lisp, runtime-error

I have this code

```
(lambda (symbol)
  (let*(
        (datalist (get-list symbol))
    (desc " ")
        (html "<table border=\"1\">")
        (html (string-append html "<tr><td>" (list-ref datalist 1) "</td><t\
r><td>" (list-ref datalist  2) "</td></tr>"))
        )
    (do ((p 7 (+ 7 p)))
    ((> p (-(length datalist) 2)))
      (desc (string-append desc "<tr><td>"(list-ref datalist p) "</td><td>"\
 (list-ref datalist (+ p 1))"</td></tr>"))
      )
    (set! html (string-append html desc "</table>"))
      html
    )
  )
```

I'm basically taking some elements from a datalist and adding some html tags to them. However, when I run the code, I get a "wrong type to apply error" on the desc binding (line 4). What gives? Even when i change it to values such as "foo", i still get the wrong type error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not in the binding, is in the loop's body:

```
(desc (string-append desc …))
```

You're trying to apply `desc` as if it were a procedure - but it's a string. So basically that part of the code is doing something equivalent to this:

```
("s1" "s2")
```

Which will result in the reported error. Perhaps you meant to do this?

```
(set! desc (string-append desc …))
```

I'll take a guess to figure out what were you trying to implement. And *do* notice how properly indenting and formatting the code helps to make it clear:

```
(lambda (symbol)
  (let* ((desc " ")
         (datalist (get-list symbol))
         (html (string-append "<table border=\"1\">"
                              "<tr><td>"
                              (list-ref datalist 1)
                              "</td><tr><td>"
                              (list-ref datalist  2)
                              "</td></tr>")))
    (do ((p 7 (+ 7 p)))
      ((> p (- (length datalist) 2)))
      (set! desc (string-append desc 
                                "<tr><td>"
                                (list-ref datalist p) 
                                "</td><td>"
                                (list-ref datalist (+ p 1))
                                "</td></tr>")))
    (string-append html desc "</table>")))
```

Comment: sorry, I don't understand how it would result in ("" 1). Could you explain that part abit more? Also: i thought i was in the binding part of the let, which explains why I did that. Is there another way to get around this without using a let in the do?

Comment: @NelsonLiu I updated my answer. In short, `desc` is a string, and in this line: `(desc (string-append desc …))` you're not assigning a value to it - you're calling it as if it were a procedure! See the (I think) fixed code. And no, `desc` was not in the binding part, because it's after the exit condition, it's in the body part.

Comment: yup, that was it! the do seems fine, however. Regardless, the code works. thanks!